# magento2.4 how to upload Pdf file

Tags: pdf, upload, file

How we can upload the PDF file in magento2.4 from admin module? We are upload PDF in  backed admin its not support magento2.4

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help you regrading the PDF:

https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/attach-pdf-to-a-product-magento-2.html#how-to-attach-pdf-to-a-product-in-magento-2